# Prove $f(x^D)\geq1$: $f$ is a log-concave density and $\frac{1-2F(x^D)}{f(x^D)}=x^D-\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability-theory, economics

## Assumptions and notation

Let $f$ be a twice-differentiable log-concave density function on $[0,1]$, and let $F$ be the corresponding distribution function. Define $x^D$ by: $$\frac{1-2F(x^D)}{f(x^D)}=x^D-\frac{1}{2}.$$

Note that the equation has exactly one solution because log-concavity of $f$ implies that $(1-F)/f$ is decreasing and $F/f$ is increasing so that $(1-2F)/f$ is a decreasing function.

> ## Conjecture I wish to prove/disprove:
>
> I conjecture that $f(x^D)\geq 1$.

The diagram below plots the two functions on each side of the equation defining $x^D$. The diagram is drawn for the distribution function $$F(x)=\frac{e^{10x}-1}{e^{10}-1}$$ which has a log-concave (in fact log-linear) density. In this example, it can be seen that $$1-2F(x^D)>\frac{1-2F(x^D)}{f(x^D)}$$ so that $f(x^D)>1$.

[image]

---

## Progress so far:

### Conjecture is true if the median $m$ is $1/2$:

In this case $x^D=m=1/2$ and it must be that $f(x^D)=f(m)=f(1/2)\geq 1$.

Proof: Suppose that $m=1/2$ and that without loss of generality the mode $M$ is at least $1/2$. Then $$\frac{1}{2}=\int_0^mf(x)dx \leq \int_0^mf(m)dx= mf(m)=\frac{1}{2}f(m),$$ where the inequality follows because $f$ is log-concave and hence unimodal, and because $m\leq M$.

### Conjecture is true for:

Log-linear densities:
$$F(x)=\frac{e^{ax}-1}{e^a-1},\qquad f(x)=\frac{ae^{ax}}{e^a-1}.$$

Power functions:
$$F(x)=x^n,\qquad f(x)=nx^{n-1}.$$

Numerical computations indicate it is also true for any beta distribution with a log-concave density.

### An example where the result does not hold ($f$ not log-concave)

Below is the diagram for the distribution $$F(x)=1-(1-x)^{1/4},$$ which is concave (and so log-concave), but has a density that is not log-concave. Here $f(x^D)<1$. Notice that the $\frac{1-2F(x)}{f(x)}$ is not decreasing on $[0,1]$. This example shows that log-concavity (or concavity) of $F$  is not sufficient for the result.

[image]

### Limiting result:

Finally from numerical computations it also appears that as a sequence of distributions ordered by first-order stochastic dominance converges to the degenerate distribution at $1$, the value of $f(x^D)$ converges from above to 2.

## Context

In case anyone is interested, here $x^D$ is the equilibrium indifferent consumer in a Hotelling model of product differentiation. Showing that $f(x^D)\geq 1$ would allow me to put an upper bound on the equilibrium prices and profits in a duopoly.

Comment: There might be some missing assumptions here, because f(x) = exp(- (x-1)^2 + B)  is a log concave density on [0,1] when integration constant exp(B) is set properly. With this density, (F/f)' = 1 - 2*(1-x)* F(x)/f(x) which is positive near 0 (since F(0)=0).

Comment: As stated in the second line under the equation defining $x^D$, log concavity of a density function $f$ implies $F/f$ is increasing so that $(F/f)'$ is positive for *all* $x$ in the support. Your example does not contradict that.

Comment: My bad. I mis-read the question. Somehow I read "F/f is decreasing"

Comment: Did you mean $f/f^{'}$ monotonically increasing?

Comment: Log concavity of $f$ is equivalent to $f/f'$ being increasing, but log concavity of $f$ also implies log concavity of $F$ and $1-F$ (which are, respectively, equivalent to $F/f$ being increasing and $(1-F)/f$ being decreasing).

Comment: Yes, thanks, I know this. For symmetric unimodal densities there is a unique solution $x^D=1/2$, and obviously $m=1/2$, so the result holds. However, I need log-concavity to ensure a unique solution for asymmetric densities, which is the case where I am having trouble. Also, I have an example of an asymmetric density that is not log concave and for which $f(x^D)<1$ (the example is $F(x)=\sqrt{x}$ which is log-concave, but the corresponding density is log-convex).

Comment: In the derivation for the $m=1/2$ you bound the integral  by $mf(m)$. Is it that $0<f(x)<m$ when $0<x<m$, especially in the case $m<M$?

Comment: Q: Is log-concavity NASC for unimodality? Also, in my previous comment and in order to bound the integral you need $m=M$ which is of course true for symmetric unimodal densities.

Comment: A density is log-concave if and only if it is strongly unimodal (i.e. its convolution with any unimodal density is unimodal). I think the edit should answer your other question.

Comment: @smcc did you check the diff equation  w.r.t. $F(x)$?

Comment: @theoGR Sorry, not sure what you are asking...

Comment: I think this equation can be written as $F^{')(x)+F(x)\cdot 4/(2x-1)=2/(2x-1)$. This is a  first  order linear diff equation. I might be missing something.

Comment: The equality holds at a unique $x$ (i.e. only at $x^D$), not all $x\in[0,1]$; it is not a differential equation. The density $f=F'$ is some arbitrary log-concave function on $[0,1]$ and I want to prove that $f(x^D)\geq 1$.

Comment: I understand but since you don't know the solution this might help to exclude some x's.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43489/discussion-between-theogr-and-smcc).

Comment: @smcc Would you be interested for an explicit form of $x^D$ ?

Comment: It's not possible to get an explicit form of $x^D$ (except in the special case where $m=x^D=1/2$ and a few other special cases). I can find $x^D$ numerically for any given example, but that doesn't help me except to test for counterexamples to my conjecture.

Comment: @smcc $F(x^D)=(f(x^D)/2)(1/2-x^D)+1/2$.  Moreover, the tangent at $x^D,F(x^D)$ is $y=F(x^D)+f(x^D)(x-x^D)$. If you substitute the value 

for $F(x^D)$  we have    $y=(f(x^D)/2)(1/2-x^D)+1/2+f(x^D)(x-x^D)$     For $x=m$ we have $y=(f(x^D)/2)(1/2-x^D)+1/2+f(x^D)(m-

x^D)=(f(x^D)/4)(4m-6x^D+1)+1/2$ If for instance $y<F(m)=1/2$you can get a bound for $x^D\geq \frac{4m+1}{6}$ .  Pls check for any errors.

Comment: Thanks, but I am aware of this bound. It does not seem to be useful in proving the result.